# parsing xml data form the internet

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing

hello guys i develop a simple app that read an XML file from the internet by using the SAX  but i get this error on logcat any help could be helpful

**manifest file**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.reaf.xml"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.read.xml.DataHandler"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Logcat**

```
10-06 07:38:00.014: D/dalvikvm(543): newInstance failed: no <init>()
10-06 07:38:00.054: D/AndroidRuntime(543): Shutting down VM
10-06 07:38:00.054: W/dalvikvm(543): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
10-06 07:38:00.064: E/AndroidRuntime(543): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-06 07:38:00.064: E/AndroidRuntime(543): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.reaf.xml/com.read.xml.DataHandler}: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.read.xml.DataHandler
10-06 07:38:00.064: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
10-06 07:38:00.064: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
10-06 07:38:00.064: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-06 07:38:00.064: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
10-06 07:38:00.064: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-06 07:38:00.064: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-06 07:38:00.064: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-06 07:38:00.064: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-06 07:38:00.064: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-06 07:38:00.064: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-06 07:38:00.064: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-06 07:38:00.064: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-06 07:38:00.064: E/AndroidRuntime(543): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.read.xml.DataHandler
10-06 07:38:00.064: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
10-06 07:38:00.064: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
10-06 07:38:00.064: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
10-06 07:38:00.064: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
10-06 07:38:00.064: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  ... 11 more
```

i did not know what is the error

please help

Comment: Share source code of com.read.xml.DataHandler , and please share edit rights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your package is `com.reaf.xml` and your activity name is `com.read.xml.DataHandler` (you have a mistake in your package name).

Please accord them by setting package to `com.read.xml` and activity name to `.DataHandler`.

Comment: Can u please explain me nore what your trying to say .. i think their no issue in having file in different package  ...

Comment: Unless there is two different packages like com.reaf.xml and com.read.xml and both having DataHandler class, it should throw ClassNotFoundException rite ?

Comment: I've already tried to define an activity which is not in the same package as defined in the AndroidManifest.xml and it never works. Never understood why it doesn't work, but it doesn't work. If anybody knows why…

Answer (score 0):

It is not able to initialize the `DataHandler` when you the call of `newInstance` method . Please ensure that you provide `nullary constructor` for `DataHandler` class. For other reasons check with the [API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29)